# Excel if statement - if not this or not that - do this

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Need some help with this formula:

```
=if(m3="No","Yes","No"),if(m3="","","")
```

If m3 = is blank(""), I want this cell to stay blank and ignore the Yes or No first part of the formula. How do I do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may nest the ifs: `if(m3="","",if(m3="No","Yes","No"))`

Comment: Legend! worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

> If m3 = is blank(""), I want this cell to stay blank and ignore the Yes or No first part of the formula.

Is this what you are trying?

```
=IF(ISBLANK(M3),"",IF(M3="No","Yes","No"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=REPT(IF(M3="No","Yes","No"),M3<>"")
```